# Can we pause audio on incoming call in flutter app?

Tags: flutter

I am using audioplayers package to play audio file. My issue is whenever there is an incoming call in my phone the audio keeps playing. Is there any way to pause the audio or generally speaking pause the whole app while answering the incoming call.

If I could pause the audio file I could somehow work around it.